# Reconocedor de voz arecord y python

Tags: python, linux

estoy intentando desarrollar un sistema de reconocimiento de voz y necesito grabar palabras "sueltas" a través de una placa similar a Raspberry.

El caso es que necesito que el programa escuche una palabra (la grabe), y entonces cuando se haya parado de hablar o de decir la palabra (haya un silencio etc) se almacene en un .raw para pasarsela a mi analizador.

Por las caracteristicas del micro y de la placa no consigo hacer que esto me funcione: http://ymkimit.blogspot.com.es/2014/07/recording-sound-detecting-silence.html -> No se me escucha nada con la orden 'record'.

He probado esto

> arecord --device=plughw:1,0 --format cd --rate 16000 -c1 test.raw

y si que me funciona pero no para cuando hay silencios etc.

Podrian ayudarme. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Por si a alguien le pasa lo mismo, al final lo consegui mediante:

```
sox -t alsa hw:1,0 record.wav rate 16k silence 1 0.1 0.1% 1 2.0 0.33% pad 0.1
```